# How to format a text in a div with jQuery/Css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to display a text copied from a site, for example Wikipedia, in a div. This text has to be strictly without the tags that the computer copies with the text from wikipedia.

I think that the solution is to set a sort of formatting of the text but I don't know.

[This](https://jsfiddle.net/wfamqvub/13/) is how it should be (Press OK). But I don't want to paste the text in the code, I have to paste the text in the textarea.

In fact if you try to paste something from Wikipedia in the textarea of this [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wfamqvub/14/) you will see that the result is horrible and with all the html tags.

HTML:

```
<div id="faketxt" contenteditable></div>
<button id='btn'>OK</button>
<button class="fontStyle" onclick="document.execCommand( 'bold',false,null);" title="Bold Highlighted Text"><b>B</b>
    </button>
        <button class="fontStyle" onclick="document.execCommand( 'underline',false,null);"><u>U</u>
    </button> <br>

<div id='boxes'>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#faketxt {
    -moz-appearance: textfield-multiline;
    -webkit-appearance: textarea;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    height: 28px;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 2px;
    resize: both;
    width: 400px;
}

.fakes{
  width: 150px;
  height: 300px;
  font-size: 10px;
  border-style: solid;
  display:inline-block;
  float: left;
}

#boxes{
  display : flex;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('#btn').click(function() {
  var primo = document.getElementById('faketxt');
  var wordLimit = 130;
  var words = primo.innerHTML.replace(/(&lt;([^&gt;]+)&gt;)/ig,"").split(/\s/);
  if (words.length) {
    var count = 0;
    var div = createDiv();
    var bold = false;
    words.forEach(function(word) {
      if (++count > wordLimit) {
        count = 1;
        div = createDiv();
      }
      if (div.innerHTML) {
        div.append(' ');
      }

      if (word.indexOf('<b>') != -1) {
        bold = true;
      }

      if (bold) {
        $(div).html($(div).html() + '<b>' +
          word + '</b>');
      } else {
        $(div).html($(div).html() +
          word);
      }

      if (word.indexOf('</b>') != -1) {
        bold = false;
      }
    });
  }
});

function createDiv() {
  div = document.createElement('div');
  div.className = 'fakes';
  document.getElementById('boxes').append(div);
  return div;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`innerHTML` or jquery's `$.html()` will pull the content (including HTML) of an element. But `textContent` or jquery's `$.text()` will just get the text.

Instead of `var words = primo.innerHTML` have you tried using `var words = primo.textContent` or `var words = $(primo).text()`?

Comment: Yes, it's working, but it doesn't make me able to use my bold and underline function.... Is there any way to use them?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how, without parsing every tag like you're doing. I can delete my answer if you like.

Comment: No,however It's the best.

Answer (score 0):

try using 
words = primo.textContent.replace(/(<^>]+)>)/ig,"").split(/\s/);
instead of 
words = primo.innerHTML.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"").split(/\s/);

Answer (score 0):

Rather than getting the innerHTML of the source, simply get the text content using either the javascript or JQuery text() functions.

So, given you are using jQuery, change your words variable to initialise as follows.

```
var words = $(primo).text().split(/\s/);
```

Comment: Yes, it's working, but it doesn't make me able to use my bold and underline buttons.... Is there any way to use them?